# The outlook send dialog doesn't show

Tags: delphi, outlook, mapi

I have a delphi 6 application wich uses mapi to open the outlook send dialog
with attachment.
This works on my PC and also on other clients PC.

I have now 2 clients where the send dialog isn't opening. I don't even get a
Error message. The clients have a W7 PC and outlook 2013.
I've tried Fixmapi, but this doesn't help.

Outlook is working fine and Via explorer the send dialogue is working fine.

Comment: As far as I know there were some considerable changes Microsoft Office API introduced in Office 2010 and newer which can easily beak compatibility with older software that still uses older API calls. This is probably also affecting Outlook 2013 integration. So I'm afraid you will have to study documentation to see what changes were made and how you must update your software to work with latest versions of Microsoft Office and programs that ship with it.

Comment: Ok. SilverWarior. Do you know where i can find the documentation?

Comment: What MAPI wrapper  are you using?

Comment: I'm using the same function from you

Answer (score 1):

I just tried MAPI and it worked for me, with thunderbird, and outlook 2013.

I did get a FIXMAPI dialog and then I got the new outlook email window, same as ever.

If you have a problem only on specific machines, then that's not a programming question, it's a windows question. Be sure to use the Control Panel to look at what default programs you have selected, including which is the default MAPI mail program.

```
program MapiSample;

uses
  {Vcl.}Forms,
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  {Vcl.}Dialogs,
  {WinApi.}MAPI;

type
  LPSTR = PAnsiChar;
  PSTR = PChar;

function SendMailMAPI(const Subject, Body, FileName, SenderName, SenderEMail,
                  RecepientName, RecepientEMail: AnsiString) : Integer;
var
  message: TMapiMessage;
  lpSender,
  lpRecepient: TMapiRecipDesc;
  FileAttach: TMapiFileDesc;
  SM: TFNMapiSendMail;
  MAPIModule: HModule;
begin
  FillChar(message, SizeOf(message), 0);
  with message do
  begin
    if (Subject<>'') then
    begin
      lpszSubject := LPSTR(Subject)
    end;
    if (Body<>'') then
    begin
      lpszNoteText := LPSTR(Body)
    end;
    if (SenderEMail<>'') then
    begin
      lpSender.ulRecipClass := MAPI_ORIG;
      if (SenderName='') then
      begin
        lpSender.lpszName := LPSTR(SenderEMail)
      end
      else
      begin
        lpSender.lpszName := LPSTR(SenderName)
      end;
      lpSender.lpszAddress := LPSTR('SMTP:'+SenderEMail);
      lpSender.ulReserved := 0;
      lpSender.ulEIDSize := 0;
      lpSender.lpEntryID := nil;
      lpOriginator := @lpSender;
    end;
    if (RecepientEMail<>'') then
    begin
      lpRecepient.ulRecipClass := MAPI_TO;
      if (RecepientName='') then
      begin
        lpRecepient.lpszName := LPSTR(RecepientEMail)
      end
      else
      begin
        lpRecepient.lpszName := LPSTR(RecepientName)
      end;
      lpRecepient.lpszAddress := LPSTR('SMTP:'+RecepientEMail);
      lpRecepient.ulReserved := 0;
      lpRecepient.ulEIDSize := 0;
      lpRecepient.lpEntryID := nil;
      nRecipCount := 1;
      lpRecips := @lpRecepient;
    end
    else
    begin
      lpRecips := nil
    end;
    if (FileName='') then
    begin
      nFileCount := 0;
      lpFiles := nil;
    end
    else
    begin
      FillChar(FileAttach, SizeOf(FileAttach), 0);
      FileAttach.nPosition := Cardinal($FFFFFFFF);
      FileAttach.lpszPathName := LPSTR(FileName);
      nFileCount := 1;
      lpFiles := @FileAttach;
    end;
  end;
  MAPIModule := LoadLibrary(PSTR(MAPIDLL));
  if MAPIModule=0 then
  begin
    Result := -1
  end
  else
  begin
    try
      @SM := GetProcAddress(MAPIModule, 'MAPISendMail');
      if @SM<>nil then
      begin
        Result := SM(0, Application.Handle, message, MAPI_DIALOG or
                     MAPI_LOGON_UI, 0);
      end
      else
      begin
        Result := 1
      end;

    finally
      FreeLibrary(MAPIModule);
    end;
  end;
  if Result<>0 then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Error sending mail ('+IntToStr(Result)+').', mtError, [mbOk],
               0)
  end;
end;

begin
    SendMailMapi('test','test','','My Name', 'sender@sender.com', 'Your Name', 'receiver@something.com');

end.
```

Comment: Hi Warren, I'm using the same Function.

Comment: How can i see which is the default mapi email program?